# OSX: pyInstaller failing to download

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyinstaller

For all packages I've installed, I've used

`pip3 install [package name]` and I haven't had any issues.

For PyInstaller I get this error message

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/st/_5np1sr92zl_34jy58rt65c40000gn/T/pip-build-env-9ad1w22t/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (44 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
```

Edit: From trying `pip3 install --no-cache-dir pyinstaller`

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/st/_5np1sr92zl_34jy58rt65c40000gn/T/pip-build-env-po9ly7dc/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: If you can't get out of it try reinstalling python from the official website or via homebrew. You can also try installing [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) again.

Comment: Can you try installing without using the cache `pip3 install --no-cache-dir pyinstaller`

Comment: @Cyclonecode same result :( I'll update my post with the output